# Monkey patching Odoo unit tests

Tags: python, odoo, monkeypatching, odoo-12

I have some customized modules which change the default workflow, thus have to re-write related unit tests. First, I monkey patched one `crm` module unit test without any issue.

The original `crm` unit test: [test_crm_ui.py on GitHub](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/crm/tests/test_crm_ui.py).

My monkey patch in a customized module:

```py
import odoo.addons.crm.tests.test_crm_ui

@odoo.tests.tagged('post_install', '-at_install')
class TestUi(odoo.addons.crm.tests.test_crm_ui.TestUi):
    def test_01_crm_tour(self):
        pass
        # ...

odoo.addons.crm.tests.test_crm_ui.TestUi = TestUi
```

**Which worked.**

Then I need to monkey patch all unit tests in `sale_mrp` module. `test_multistep_manufacturing.py` for example: [original on GitHub](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/sale_mrp/tests/test_multistep_manufacturing.py).

First I tried below, similar to what I did to `crm`.

```py
import odoo.addons.sale_mrp.tests.test_multistep_manufacturing

class ReplaceTestMultistepManufacturing(odoo.addons.sale_mrp.tests.test_multistep_manufacturing.TestMultistepManufacturing):
    def setUp(self):
        pass
        # ...
    def test_00_manufacturing_step_one(self):
        pass
        # ...

odoo.addons.sale_mrp.tests.test_multistep_manufacturing.TestMultistepManufacturing = ReplaceTestMultistepManufacturing
```

Which did **not** work, maybe the actual module was not really patched. Then I tried below.

```py
from odoo.addons.sale_mrp.tests import test_multistep_manufacturing

class ReplaceTestMultistepManufacturing(test_multistep_manufacturing.TestMultistepManufacturing):
    def setUp(self):
        pass
        # ...
    def test_00_manufacturing_step_one(self):
        pass
        # ...

test_multistep_manufacturing.TestMultistepManufacturing = ReplaceTestMultistepManufacturing
```

Which also did **not** work. Actually two attempts resulted the same - both the new test **and** the original test was run.

Am I doing monkey patch wrong or I need to do something special in Odoo? Thanks!

Comment: check again may be you miss spell some variable because It should work, but I didn't see any class named `TestMultistepManufacturing` In odoo github code!!!

Comment: @EasyOdoo My apologies... ```TestMultistepManufacturing``` was in ```test_multistep_manufacturing.py```, was too tired last night and didn't notice I put the wrong info. I have updated the question and link. I feel the original test is already doing monkey patch to ```TestMrpCommon```, is it okay to monkey patch a monkey patch?

Comment: I don't think is monkey patching it's like duplicating the test, and adding new ones. from the way I see it. really don't know what will happen when you declare a new class that inherit a class is it overriding, or duplicating or just adding didn't think about that